# Copied Access database to SQL Server fine but parameter input query fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, database-migration, parameterized-query

```
strSql = "Insert into History [sDate], [sCode], etc)"
trSql = strSql & " Values(p1, p2, etc);"

 If cn.State = 0 Then cn.Open

 With cmd
.ActiveConnection = cn
.CommandText = strSql
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p1", 
adDate, adParamInput, 10, strdate)
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p2", 
adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, strcode)
end with
```

The above code is a shortened version of the query that fails with an error:

> Invalid column name 'p1'.

This looks like SQL Server doesn't understand these parameter queries at all.
I can't find any documentation to help. Does anyone know if there I a shot fix or I have to completely rewrite a dozen or more large insert and update queries.

If I have to replace them, is a stored procedure the best option?

Comment: What front end language is this written in?

Comment: You don't have to use stored procedures but that is definitely what I would prefer over using VBA to do pass through queries.

Comment: Try `strSql = strSql & " Values(@p1,@p2, @etc);"`.

Comment: Its written in VBA behind an excel frontend

Comment: Nice idea Wolfgang. I really expected it to work, but no change.
I think the sizes of my nvarchars may also be an issue one it gets to recognize parameters.
I used to work with SQL server a lot from ASP and I am convinced that these parameter queries though ado used to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to be explicit with the table call and see if that works.

Have you attempted to use `dbo.History` instead of just `History`?

Of course if this is a table specific to your logon, then you will want to use whatever default schema is set for that logon instead of `dbo`.

Comment: OK thanks for the advice all.
I have written stored procedures for all the queries as advised and they work great.